# End-to-end Encryption of Whatsapp

Tags: encryption, whatsapp

I have a question about Whatsapp's end-to-end encryption. As you know, Whatsapp claims that no one (including Whatsapp) can read messages or listen to the calls.

How can Whatsapp guarantee such a thing? Doesn't it have access to the keys of the users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatsapp has access to the key on one side but not on the other one.

This is called
[Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography),
defined as:

> Public-key cryptography, or asymmetric cryptography, is a
> cryptographic system that uses pairs of keys. Each pair consists of a
> public key (which may be known to others) and a private key (which may
> not be known by anyone except the owner).
>
> In such a system, any person can encrypt a message using the intended
> receiver's public key, but that encrypted message can only be
> decrypted with the receiver's private key.

If you're interested, information is amply available on the internet.
The above Wikipedia article can start you on the way.